# CC.Net Interval trigger

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I have setup continuos build in cruise control. I have set interval trigger to be 30 seconds. My question here is if my commit takes longer than 30 seconds, will cruise control wait till my commit is finished or will it trigger a build at 30th second?

Answer (score 2):

what do you mean 'commit takes longer than 30 seconds'?
you really mean : putting the changes in source control?

If so, adjust your source control block with the timeout settings, but I do not know if all source control blocks have it, VSS does because it is not atomic.

All modern source-controls are atomic, CCNet does not see a change until the entire commit is done, no matter how long that takes.

Comment: Agreed.  The "atomic" nature should make this a non-issue.

Comment: Note, IIRC, the CC.NET SVN checkout uses a timestamp......that stays consistent during "a build".  Check the logs...and see what command line argument is being used.  If you're not using SVN, then look for a similar method.

Comment: Even if you use svn with timestamps, it will not be an issue, since the change is only visible after the commit (atomic). But you can force CCNet to use the svn revision number : UseRevsionNumbers=true in svn-sourcecontrol block